# improving curve fitting in python

Tags: python, scipy, data-analysis, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I have the following data and a function fitted to it using scipy's curve_fitting function.

I am currently fitting the following function: f(x): a*(1-exp(-b*x)); But it can be any function but need to be monotonically increasing or non-decreasing. 
[image]

However, for my purpose I do not want the flat curve. I want that there should always be a gradient > 0.001.

What can I do to add this gradient to the curve so that it looks not so flat after the initial rise.
Something like this: 
[image]

I was thinking of adding a dummy data point at the end of x axis whose y axis value is higher than 0 (in this example), hoping that it will add a gradient.

But is there a better way to do what I intend.

Comment: use `a**2 * ( 1 - exp( -b**2 * x) ) + ( 0.001 + c**2) * x` or only the last part...

Comment: ...strange data, though....is it only 0 and 1?

Comment: not 1 and 0 .. it could be other points also...

Comment: did not understand what is meant by " only the last part.."

Comment: .. I mean `( 0.001 + c**2) * x ` alone would also be a monotonic function